# How to run applet through browser?

Tags: javascript, java, html, browser, applet

When I try to run the applet through the browser it either shows the text in HTML file and box that says require a plugin to show Java content or applet, or it just shows the text in the HTML file. And when I click on the plugin it says cant be installed. And also people also say that there should be .class file but I only have .java and the .html file.

This is the code of the Java class:

```
package applet;

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

/**
*
* @author Karan
*/
public class applet extends Applet{

/**
 * @param g
 */
public void output(Graphics g) 
{
    g.drawString("Karan Raaj Singh",100,200);
}
}
```

This is the HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test run Applet </title>
</head>
<body>
<center>Hi, this is my first applet</center>
<center><applet
        code=applet.class
        height=200
        width=100>
    </applet></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're supposed to compile (`javac`) your .java file into a .class file, and you're not supposed to use applets any longer, it's dead technology, read about Java Web Start instead.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: `public void output(Graphics g) 
{
    g.drawString("Karan Raaj Singh",100,200);` What makes you think that method will ever be called? It should be `@Override public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
    g.drawString("Karan Raaj Singh",100,200);`